# Can this method reach 100% code coverage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, exception, code-coverage

I have the following method:

```
public static async Task<bool> CreateIfNotExistsAsync(
    this ISegment segment, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Requires.ArgNotNull(segment, nameof(segment));

    try
    {
        await segment.CreateAsync(cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        if (error.CanSuppress() && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var status = await segment.GetStatusAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (status.Exists)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

...for which I have written tests that should cover all blocks. However; Code Coverage Results (in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3) shows that two blocks aren't covered:

[image: Two blocks not covered]

I figured this had something to do with the code that is generated for `await` inside a catch-block, so I tried rewriting the method like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> CreateIfNotExistsAsync(
    this ISegment segment, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Requires.ArgNotNull(segment, nameof(segment));

    ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedError;

    try
    {
        await segment.CreateAsync(cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        if (error.CanSuppress() && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            capturedError = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(error);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    var status = await segment.GetStatusAsync(cancellationToken);
    if (!status.Exists)
    {
        capturedError.Throw();
    }

    return false;
}
```

However, there is still one block that isn't covered:

[image: Still not fully covered]

Is it possible to rewrite this method so that it can be fully covered?

---

Here are my related tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Create_if_not_exists_returns_true_when_create_succeed()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISegment>();
    Assert.IsTrue(await mock.Object.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(default(CancellationToken)));
    mock.Verify(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task Create_if_not_exists_throws_when_create_throws_and_cancellation_is_requested()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISegment>();
    var exception = new Exception();

    mock.Setup(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Throws(exception);

    try
    {
        await mock.Object.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(new CancellationToken(true));
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception caught)
    {
        Assert.AreSame(exception, caught);
    }

    mock.Verify(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    mock.Verify(_ => _.GetStatusAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Never);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task Create_if_not_exists_throws_when_create_throws_non_suppressable_exception()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISegment>();
    var exception = new OutOfMemoryException();

    mock.Setup(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Throws(exception);

    try
    {
        await mock.Object.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(default(CancellationToken));
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception caught)
    {
        Assert.AreSame(exception, caught);
    }

    mock.Verify(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    mock.Verify(_ => _.GetStatusAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Never);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task Create_if_not_exists_throws_when_create_throws_and_status_says_segment_doesnt_exists()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISegment>();
    var exception = new Exception();

    mock.Setup(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Throws(exception);
    mock.Setup(_ => _.GetStatusAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new SegmentStatus(false, false, null, 0));

    try
    {
        await mock.Object.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(default(CancellationToken));
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception caught)
    {
        Assert.AreSame(exception, caught);
    }

    mock.Verify(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    mock.Verify(_ => _.GetStatusAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task Create_if_not_exists_returns_false_when_create_throws_and_status_says_segment_exists()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISegment>();

    mock.Setup(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Throws<Exception>();
    mock.Setup(_ => _.GetStatusAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new SegmentStatus(true, false, null, 0));

    Assert.IsFalse(await mock.Object.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(default(CancellationToken)));

    mock.Verify(_ => _.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    mock.Verify(_ => _.GetStatusAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
}
```

---

This is the `CanSuppress`-logic:

```
private static readonly Exception[] EmptyArray = new Exception[0];

/// <summary>
///     Determines whether an <see cref="Exception"/> can be suppressed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="exception">
///     The <see cref="Exception"/> to test.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
///     <c>true</c> when <paramref name="exception"/> can be suppressed; otherwise <c>false</c>.
/// </returns>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
///     We do not want to suppress <see cref="OutOfMemoryException"/> or <see cref="ThreadAbortException"/> 
///     or any exception derived from them (except for <see cref="InsufficientMemoryException"/>, which we
///     do allow suppression of).
/// </para>
/// <para>
///     An exception that is otherwise suppressable is not considered suppressable when it has a nested 
///     non-suppressable exception.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
public static bool CanSuppress(this Exception exception)
{
    foreach (var e in exception.DescendantsAndSelf())
    {
        if ((e is OutOfMemoryException && !(e is InsufficientMemoryException)) ||
            e is ThreadAbortException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static IEnumerable<Exception> DescendantsAndSelf(this Exception exception)
{
    if (exception != null)
    {
        yield return exception;

        foreach (var child in exception.Children().SelectMany(ExceptionExtensions.DescendantsAndSelf))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<Exception> Children(this Exception parent)
{
    DebugAssumes.ArgNotNull(parent, nameof(parent));

    var aggregate = parent as AggregateException;

    if (aggregate != null)
    {
        return aggregate.InnerExceptions;
    }
    else if (parent.InnerException != null)
    {
        return new[] { parent.InnerException };
    }
    else
    {
        return ExceptionExtensions.EmptyArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first picture, which blocks are not being covered..?

Comment: I guess Blue means covered; Orange means not covered; Purpleish means partially covered. So I would say `throw;` and `}` although `throw` **is** covered and `}` isn't even code to be covered...

Comment: The `}` isn't something 'coverable', and I'm guessing it's not highlighted because code never falls out of that scope (which is fine - the same thing happens after the return statements). As for the throw, it's nothing to do with the structure, it's because the exception is suppressible and the task wasn't cancelled. So, you'll need to write a new test (with the original code) that causes a non suppressible exception, or cancel the task

Comment: No, I am testing that case (as you can see in the second version). The code is reported as "not covered" because of something "under the hood" (that's my guess anyway).

Comment: I have a test for that. An exception is thrown, it is suppressable, token is not cancelled and status says segment doesn't exist. This test reaches `throw`. Still it isn't blue in code coverage result...

Comment: Hmm, you're right - I misread it. I'd lookup the documentation for the code coverage tool. It might be purple because it sees two paths to the code, but only one path is taken (thus the line is 'covered', but not all logical paths to it are). In your first snippet, `throw` may be hit because the if statement is false, however, the secondary path (when `status.Exists` is false) might not ever execute. The same can be deduced about the purple line in your second snippet.

Comment: To prove this, I would change your first snippet to be `if (status.Exists) { return false; } else { throw; }` and see if both the `throw`s are covered.

Comment: I did try that, then have two `throw;` statements. One inside the `else` and the original one from the first snippet. I set a breakpoint on each of them and run tests in debug mode. Indeed both breakpoints are hit. But they're still not blue...

Comment: I've attempted to replicate your setup - using `dotCover`, I do indeed have every line covered (including the extra explicit throw path). What tool are you using for code coverage?

Comment: How kind of you to take time for this! Thank you. I'm using the tool included in Visual Studio 2015. Also; please see my recent edit for `CanSuppress`-logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright - after a huge amount of digging - the culprit is `await segment.GetStatusAsync(cancellationToken)`. This causes the code coverage to view `throw` as *partially* covered. Replacing that line with a non-async method correctly shows `throw` as being covered

Now, `async` creates a state machine internally. You can see this in the code coverage, it finds a method named

`<CreateIfNotExistsAsync>d__1.MoveNext:`

Among the IL generated, *this* popped out to me:

```
IL_01B4:  ldfld       MyExtensions+<CreateIfNotExistsAsync>d__1.<>s__1
IL_01B9:  isinst      System.Exception
IL_01BE:  stloc.s     0A 
IL_01C0:  ldloc.s     0A 
IL_01C2:  brtrue.s    IL_01CB
IL_01C4:  ldarg.0     
IL_01C5:  ldfld       MyExtensions+<CreateIfNotExistsAsync>d__1.<>s__1
IL_01CA:  throw       
IL_01CB:  ldloc.s     0A 
IL_01CD:  call        System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture
IL_01D2:  callvirt    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
```

Here, there are two ways the exception is thrown:

```
IL_01B4:  ldfld       MyExtensions+<CreateIfNotExistsAsync>d__1.<>s__1
IL_01B9:  isinst      System.Exception
IL_01BE:  stloc.s     0A 
IL_01C0:  ldloc.s     0A 
IL_01C2:  brtrue.s    IL_01CB
IL_01C4:  ldarg.0     
IL_01C5:  ldfld       MyExtensions+<CreateIfNotExistsAsync>d__1.<>s__1
IL_01CA:  throw
```

This is essentially taking the field from `s__1`, and checking if it's an `Exception` type. For example:  `machine.state1 is Exception`

Then, if it's true, it branches to `IL_01CB`

```
IL_01CB:  ldloc.s     0A 
IL_01CD:  call        System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture
IL_01D2:  callvirt    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
```

Which throws the exception. However, if it's *false*, it invokes the `throw` OpCode.

This means that `throw` is translated into two possible paths, only one of which is ever executed. I'm not sure it's possible in C# for `IL_01B9:  isinst      System.Exception` to ever be false, but I may be wrong - or it may be possible in .NET generally.

The bad news is, I don't have a solution for it. My advice is: use code coverage as a *guideline*, as even 100% coverage doesn't mean code is free of bugs. Having said that, you can logically deduce `throw` being marked as 'partially covered' in essentially the same as being fully covered

Comment: Thank you for this effort! I'm still hoping to find a way to get Visual Studio to report the code as fully covered - since it really is that.

Comment: @MårtenWikström I can only recommend another tool - for example, `dotCover` - which analyses lines of code executed, rather than IL execution. I'm not sure whether the built in coverage is configurable in this way. Curiously, the IL *appears* to me to be redundant, as it previously checks that the object is an exception, though the functionality still remains even when compiling with optimizations